# How to add an empty field to csv file if it is null?

Tags: c#, csv

I'm writing some data in c# to a csv file and some fields are showing up as null when I add everthing without checking for whether it's null, I'd like for them to just be empty in excel format.  So I did:

```
if (a!= null)
      insert(a)
else insert("");
```

Which is 3 lines and I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this since I have to test this for multiple entries.

Comment: so what's the question? looks like you answered your question in the question.

Comment: it's 3 lines and I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this since I have to test this for multiple entries

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)(`??`):

```
insert(a ?? "");
```